# TypeScript module Augmentation (again...)

Tags: typescript

OK... this is my last resort...
I try to augment "Dictionary" from "typescript-collections" (https://github.com/basarat/typescript-collections/blob/release/src/lib/index.ts)

`typescript-collections` exports the Dictionary like this:

```js
export { default as Dictionary } from './Dictionary';
```

My augmented version should have a function "sort"

Here is what I have so far

**src/augment.d.ts:**

```js
import { Dictionary } from 'typescript-collections';

declare module 'typescript-collections' {
    export interface Dictionary<K, V> {
        sort(): Dictionary<K, V>;
    }
}
```

**src/main/extensions/ts-collection.ts:**

```js
import { Dictionary } from 'typescript-collections';

// TS (WebStorm) shows my an error on "sort"
// Property "sort" does not exist on type "Dictionary<K, V>"...
Dictionary.prototype.sort = function<K, V>(): Dictionary<K, V> {
    const sortedDict = new Dictionary<K, V>();

    this.keys()
        .sort()
        .forEach((key) => {
            const value = this.getValue(key);
            if (value) {
                sortedDict.setValue(key, value);
            }
        });

    return sortedDict;
};
```

augment.d.ts is included in tsconfig.json

**mytest.spec.ts:** (Jest-Test)

```js
import { Dictionary } from 'typescript-collections';

    test('sort via prototype', () => {
        let dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        dict.setValue('a', 'a1');
        dict.setValue('c', 'c1');
        dict.setValue('b', 'b1');

        expect(dict.keys()).toIncludeAllMembers(['a', 'b', 'c']);

        expect(dict.keys().sort()[1]).toBe('b');

        // Error: Property "sort" does not exist on...
        dict = dict.sort();

        expect(dict.keys()[0]).toBe('a');
        expect(dict.keys()[1]).toBe('b');
        expect(dict.keys()[2]).toBe('c');
    });
```

*[Update]*
My problem is that WebStorm shows me the error in ts-collection.ts (see code-comment) and that I can't use sort in mytest.spec.ts (also code-comment)

Comment: Hi, could you clarify what your question is? Do you get an error? Does it simply not work?

Comment: Thanks - I've updated my question. The problem was described as code-comment...